# Creating table for wordpress plugin not being created

Tags: csv, import, wordpress, create-table

I am trying to redesign my previous code into a plugin but I have run into some issues.  When I try to create a table using the below code.  The table is not created.  I tried to debug but I get no errors :S

Appreciate if you can have a look at the code.  I also have another question.  After I create the table I need to populate it via a csv file.  Do you guys have any idea how to go around this as I have no idea where to start.

Thanks again

```
function upper_table(){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "upper_winds";
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name){
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name ( 
`LVL` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
`REGION` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`VALID` INT NOT NULL, 
`CURRENT` TEXT NOT NULL 
);";
//reference to upgrade.php file
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
```

}
   }

This code is in a functions php file and is called from the main plugin via

```
include ("functions_wx.php");
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'upper_table');
```

The sql query above has been passed through PHPmyAdmin directly and has worked fined.  Do not know if it could be a problem but I am currently running through WAMP server.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name ( 
`LVL` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
`REGION` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`VALID` INT NOT NULL, 
`CURRENT` TEXT NOT NULL 
);";
```

With

```
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$table_name." ( 
`LVL` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
`REGION` TEXT NOT NULL, 
`VALID` INT NOT NULL, 
`CURRENT` TEXT NOT NULL 
);";
```

(Notice the quotes and dots around the table name)

If that doesn't work, you can debug by var dumping the variable $table_name to ensure it contains a valid string:

```
var_dump($table_name);
```

If it does, then try storing the return value of the dbDelta() function in a variable instead of just calling the function, like this: `$result = dbDelta( $sql );`

Then var_dump the result like this: `var_dump($result);`

That way you can begin to understand where at in your code the problem resides, and whether its an issue with your syntax/variables or the dbDelta() function you're using.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Found out that the problem lied when the activation hook was called.